# Hive how to combine multiple records within a group based on condition

Tags: hive, hiveql, hadoop2

i have dataset as following.

```
client-Id   Name    HasCar     HasHome
A01          ABC      Y          N
A01          ABC      N          N
B01          EFG      N          N
B01          EFG      N          Y
```

From here I need to derive a Single row for each customer whether he has car or home. the expected output should look like below

```
Client-Id    Name    HasCar     HasHome
A01          ABC      Y          N
B01          EFG      N          Y
```

This needs to be done using a Hive-QL

Comment: can you show us your attempt as well?

Comment: I tried the following
 1) Using a case statement with a sub-query but hive doesnt support subquery in case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use max() aggregation:

```
select client-Id,Name, max(HasCar) HasCar,  max(HasHome) HasHome
  from your_table 
 group by client-Id,Name
```